# Shifting The Result of Regression Model By N-Value

Tags: python, regression, predictive-modeling, random-forest

I am doing a multivariable regression problem, which predicts the frequency of a failure mode in a production system. In this problem, I used XGBRF for Regression as my ML model.

These are the results of walking forward predictions over 6 months compared to the actual data:

[image: Prediction Result]

From experiments on the hyperparameters and other datasets, It seems that my model will always over-predict. (no negative errors)

So, my point is, is it a valid practice to just use this model, then straightly subtract a number (for example 1 or 2) to "improve" the result?
For example, from the result above into this one below:

[image: Shifted Prediction]

I am new to the machine learning modeling world and statistics. And maybe this is a basic no-go. But I'd like to know if this practice is fine or not. Please enlighten me.